# Three way AOV, NA for one factor level

Tags: r

I am trying to run an aov for the following data:

```
y <-c(1.2436117, 1.1916385,1.2815385,1.0796698,1.0324549,1.2612003,1.1870270,1.0224868,
    1.3160909,1.4456661, 1.2621604, 1.1486878, 1.1419192,1.4642487, 1.3979747, 1.2797348, 
    1.1251773, 1.3424320, 1.3724138, 0.9690937, 1.1983471, 1.2595455, 1.1114551, 1.2379195, 
    1.1873457, 1.2309711, 1.2038194, 1.1584071, 1.1668421, 1.1596491,1.2998953, 0.9825328)
Loc <- as.factor(c(rep("A",16),rep("B",16)))
Farm <- as.factor(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8))
Treat <-as.factor(c(rep(c("AI","BC","BCF","C"),8)))
dfr <- data.frame(y,Loc,Farm,Treat)
```

USING an AOV:

```
mod <- aov(y~Loc+Farm+Treat,data=dfr)
summary(mod)
summary.lm(mod)
```

However, for the factor Farm only 6 Df are used, but it should be 7 as it has got 8 factor levels and it becomes visible in the summary.lm output that no values could be calculated for the last factor level of Farm.
I am not sure where my mistake is. But I would appreciate any advice a lot.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

ANOVA is not appropriate in this case. Unique values of "Farm" are nested (not crossed) within values of "Loc":

```
library(tidyverse)

dfr %>% 
  count(Loc, Farm)

  Loc Farm n
1   A    1 4
2   A    2 4
3   A    3 4
4   A    4 4
5   B    5 4
6   B    6 4
7   B    7 4
8   B    8 4
```

The expectation for standard ANOVA is that all factors are fully crossed (i.e., all levels of "Farm" would appear under all levels of "Loc").

What you have here is a nested or hierarchical design in which the value of "Farm" depends directly on the value of "Loc". You may wish to consider a mixed effect model. The **lme4** package is good for this. Mixed effect models have flexible specifications, but one option would be the following. I do not know the details of your experiment design and cannot say for sure that this is correct, but for example:

```
library(lme4)
mod2 <- lmer(y ~ Treat + Farm + (1|Loc/Farm), data = dfr)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, it helped a lot. Could I send a draft of my experimental design to confirm whether the above stated mixed effect model is appropriate?